# make list of integers from text file in java

Tags: java

Im trying to make it so based on the user inputted number, I compare that to series of numbers in a separate file and pick the numbers that are larger than the inputted number.

I have this so far:

```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     String line = null;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

I only got it to read the file but I dont know how to do the whole "comparing" step. I figure I need to somehow define each number in the file and compare it to the users number. The text file looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

If the user picks the number 4, I want it to print "There are 3 numbers bigger than 4" or something to that extent.

I think I need to make a list of the numbers from the file but I dont know how to do it. Im just a beginner. I just really dont know where to go from here. If there is a similar question with solution, please link it. Id appreciate any help/advice. PLease help me. TY in advance.

Comment: Start by printing out what is there in `line` ?

Comment: If i print 'line' it just prints all the content in the text file, so I left that part out...

Comment: Wow you know when your assignment is ridiculous when no one can do it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an ArrayList to store the data.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Integer userInputAsInteger = Integer.parseInt(line);
    if(userInputAsInteger > num){
      list.add(userInputAsInteger );
}
}
```

Then you can use this list to get the number of elements larger than num:

```
System.out.println(list.size() + " numbers are larger then " + num);
```

You can also print out the numbers:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but I dont quite understand what Integer int is? If you meant int Integer, it still doesnt work because int is being derefrenced in the parse statement. Im so confused. :(

Comment: The variable line is of type String. So you can't compare them easily. Therefore I transform this String to a Integer. Integer is a class which holds numbers;) 
"Integer int" hust means that I declare a new variable of the type Integer and I name this variable int.

Comment: Oh ok i see....but how come when I try compiling it says Integer is not a statement, proceeded by other errors.

Comment: Oh sry. Please rename the name of the variable int. int is a java keyword and can't be used. I will update the code ;)

Comment: I am so sorry but it still doesnt work. Ive tried fixing here and there but I keep getting Warning: unchecked conversion
  required: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>
  found:    java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Which version of Java do you use???? Seems to be a very old one. You can perhaps try to replace that line by: ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: Even if you are Using  Dr.Java you need to know first what version is installed. Check you java version in the cmd with this comand `java -version`

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of Streams and Java 8 to solve your problem

```js
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
  long n = stream.mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
    .filter(readNumber -> readNumber > num)
    .count();
  System.out.println("There are " + n + " numbers in the file greater than " + num);
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Supposing `fileName` contains the name of the file and `num` the number the user selected, open the file using a try-with-resources and create a `Stream` with the lines of the file. Map the stream to a Stream of ints and then filter it to get only those values greater than `num`. Lastly, apply count in order to get the number of elements that satisfy the predicate and print the message.

Hope it helps.